# Breaking up Python list into smaller lists?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the IN operation in a Google App Engine query is limited to 30 items in the list per query, so I have to find a way to break up the list into multiple lists with a maximum of 30 items in each array, and query each sub array.

I've come up with a small solution to do this, but it's very inelegant, and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. I'm new to Python, so I'm wondering how I might do this correctly or more elegantly?

I'm querying for `User.query(User.email IN emails)`

```
max_length = 30
iter_count = len(emails) / max_length
for i in range(iter_count):         
    min = i  * max_length
    max = (i + 1) * max_length
    if min > len(emails):
       break
    if max > len(emails):
       max = len(emails)

    current_array = emails[min:max]
    # query this array
```

Comment: This is quite an expensive query. Every element in the list results in a seperate query. Checking all the entities is sometimes cheaper.

Comment: @voscausa what do you mean by checking all the entities?

Comment: The limit is there because doing this many queries is silly expensive. Consider refactoring so you can look up entities by key instead of doing queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
max_length = 30
for i in xrange(0, len(emails), max_length):
    current_array = emails[i:i+max_length]
    # query this array
```

Comment: My, you're busy tonight :) -- put this all in a generator and you can iterate over that and hide all of the scary stuff (although, that's just cosmetic at that point)...

Comment: Yeah, I usually make a little generator `def chunk_list(l, chunksize=50)` when I need it. Comes in useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
l=range(105)
step=30
print [l[i:i+step] for i in range(0,len(l),step)]
```

Which you can easily turn into a generator:

```
>>> l=range(105)
>>> step=30
>>> g=(l[i:i+step] for i in range(0,len(l),step))
>>> g.next()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
>>> g.next()
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```